# Relative Layout positioning

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a `Relative Layout` that has an icon with a vertical line centered below it and text to the right of both of those. The text will be a paragraph so the line should be as long as the text minus the size of the icon. Right now my layout displays the icon and the text properly but I do not see the vertical line at all. This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I imagine that I would have to add additional padding to my `View` to center it once I actually get it to display

[image]

Comment: Can you attach an image of what it looks like now, to make understanding your post easier?

Comment: Have you try using a linear layout seems to me that it would be easier with it, but please provide a mockup or image of what you want to achieve!!

Comment: I attached an image of what it currently looks like. And I was considering a linear layout to get two columns but I thought a Relative Layout would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of the padding you added to the vertical line. Basically you have a view width of 2dp, yet you have 4dp of padding so nothing shows. Update your view tag to this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon" />
```

The layout you posted doesn't seem like it's going to do what you want. Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/icon"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/left_container" />
```

Comment: This yields the same result as my original code. The icon and the text are in the same position, but no vertical line

Comment: Try changing the background color of your vertical line to something like red, just to see if its the same color as your background.android:background="@android:color/red"

Comment: Yeah, no matter what color I change it to it's still not showing

Comment: Also, if I make the view horizontal (setting height to 2dp and width to match parent) it works fine, but if I set height to match or fill parent it disappears so it seems like there is an issue with inheriting the height

Comment: Idk what to tell you, it just tested it again by creating a layout and it worked fine. Maybe you should give up programming?

Comment: That probably makes the most sense